# Passing multiple array to drupal_json_output() is not giving correct output in jquery ajax

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

Passing multiple array to drupal_json_output() is not giving correct output in jquery ajax.

I am using a menu_callback function and returning a multiple array like

```
function test_callback() {
   for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr = array('message' => 'test'.$i, 'data' => 'data'.$i);
    $arrs[] = $arr;
   }
 drupal_json_output($arrs);
}
```

Now, in the jquery, I wrote like this,

```
$.ajax({
url: the above url,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
$(data).each(function(key,val) {
  console.log(val.message);
});
})
});
```

The output in the console is giving an object.

I tried to use `$.each` for the val also, but the output it is returning as undefined. I tried in a lot of ways using `$.get` etc. but not getting the output. Can anyone help me here??

Comment: The return of the array in json format should be correct. When calling your service URL directly in browser, do you have an output only containing the array or also some HTML code from the theme (doctype, <head>, ...)?

Comment: No, I am returning only the array. Does not contain any HTML code

Comment: Could you dump out a portion of the returned JS object into the question? I can't see any reason it wouldn't be coming back as an array, it would interesting to see the exact format you get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To setup a service which returns a json formatted data, you should set the `delivery callback` to `drupal_json_output`. This will only output the service data and not all the HTML defined in your theme.

For example

```
function YOURMODULE_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['service/ajax'] = array(
        'title' => t('Ajax service'),
        'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_ajax',
        'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function YOURMODULE_ajax()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $arr = array('message' => 'test'.$i, 'data' => 'data'.$i);
        $arrs[] = $arr;
    }

    return $arrs;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I will try this.

Comment: Ok, let me know if it works.

Comment: Wouldn't the delivery callback be `ajax_deliver`? I've never seen `drupal_json_output` used for that purpose before. Core and contrib use `ajax_deliver`

Comment: @MikeVranckx: I have disabled php_json in previously. Now, after checking the settings, I have enabled the json extension and it worked like a charm without using the delivery callback. Anyway thanks for your post.

Comment: @KiranTej Ok good and you're welcome.
@Clive I'm using `drupal_json_output` to return a custom json response with correct response header. `ajax_deliver` would also return as json but with extra data / commands added by Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to let the ajax call know that the response is in JSON, once give a try to the following code:

```
// Callback function of ajax (PHP file).
function test_callback() {
  for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr = array('message' => 'test'.$i, 'data' => 'data'.$i);
    $arrs[] = $arr;
  }

  // Returns data in JSON format.
  drupal_json_output($arrs);
}

// Js code for making an ajax call, and handling the response of ajax.
$.ajax({
  url: the above url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
  // Check the reponse data in the firebug console.
  console.log(data);

  /** Commenting the code for now, once you get the data than uncomment this.
  $(data).each(function(key,val) {
    console.log(val.message);
  });
  */
}, 'json');
```